# Magento a href redirect with base URL

Tags: magento2

I am new in Magento framework, i'm using a href for another website url but here it's redirect with base url, for example i need to redirect with this url  www.example.com but it's redirect to www.product.com/www.example.com

Comment: Can you please upload your a href code?

Comment: <a href="www.example.com" target="_blank">

Comment: Try to use like `<a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">`